# How to get variable from PreferenceActivity to MainActivity?

Tags: java, android, preferences, preferencescreen

This question seems dumb, but I just cant figure out how to get the boolean, which is set by a `CheckBoxPreference` in the `SettingsActivity`, to my `MainActivity`.

**CheckBoxPreference:**

```xml
<CheckBoxPreference
   android:defaultValue="true"
   android:key="check_box_show_idle_dialog"
   android:title="Show welcome dialog" />
```

**SettingsActivity:**

```java
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class SettingsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

   public static final String KEY_PREF_CHECK_BOX_SHOW_IDLE_DIALOG = "check_box_show_idle_dialog";

   Boolean show_idle_dialog;

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
         .replace(android.R.id.content, new SettingsFragment())
         .commit();

      SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

      //Switch Dark Mode
      show_idle_dialog  = sharedPreferences.getBoolean(SettingsActivity.KEY_PREF_CHECK_BOX_SHOW_IDLE_DIALOG, true);
   }
}
```

What do I have to change in order to grab the variable in the `MainActivity`? I haven't attached it, because literally could not find a single piece of code, which worked for me. Maybe it was just the wrong search terms. I would be very happy if someone has got a solution.

Comment: Your code looks ok. What is the problem?

Comment: I don't know how to transfer the value of "show_idle_dialog" to the MainActivity? Is it just like every other variable? If yes, do I just go with the Intent putExtra?

Comment: You can use the same code in every activity to get a value from shared preferences for  a variable like `show_idle_dialog`.

Comment: Oh, I didnt know that ,nevertheless it just outputs the defaultValue in the MainActivity.

Comment: That is strange.